# Deserializing an XML document into an Addressbook

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I have searched through multiple examples at this point all detailing different methods of Deserializing, Serializing or even other random unrelated processes which I probably should have ignored but kept reading anyway out of desperation.

I want to Deserialize this XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AddressBook>
<Contact>
    <Name>Steve Man</Name>
        <ContactType>Family</ContactType>
        <DateofBirth>1992-07-10T00:00:00</DateofBirth>
        <AddressLine1>123 Fake Street</AddressLine1>
        <AddressLine2>New Worthington</AddressLine2>
        <AddressLine3>Regalpark</AddressLine3>
        <AddressLine4 />
        <Postcode>RP3 6BG</Postcode>
        <Email1>Steve@gmail.com</Email1>
        <Email2>Steve@tiscali.co.uk</Email2>
        <Phone>01422951283</Phone>
        <Mobile>07559213822/Mobile>
        <AdditionalInfo>This is that weird guy.</AdditionalInfo>
</Contact>
```

Into the above mentioned AddressBook object in a C# windows form application, the contents of which will come from the data in the XML document.

After being Deserialized (or so I'm told) I can then use the objects it makes from this process directly with the Application itself, meaning I can Display/Edit/Delete them as need be.

Then after edits have been made the new data would need to be Serialized back into the original XML format for storage.

I apologize if this comes across as a stupid/duplicate question but I'm pretty new to C# and have had a long time of reading and struggling and would greatly appreciate any input you can provide, if the question needs any adjusting or you need more info then I will be happy to provide it.

Comment: What is this _AddressBook object_ ?

Comment: @TaW The object itself would act similarly to that of a contact list in applications such as Outlook or Skype, sorry for the lack of detail on that point.

Comment: Without details on the class you to deserialize you will have to make up a compatible structure/class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would like to point you to this page.
http://azuliadesigns.com/xml-serialization-deserialization/

You should use this code to serialize a list of Contact objects.
I believe below code should do the trick for you

```
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Contact>));
    StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter("c:/addressbook.xml");
    mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, test);
    myWriter.Close();
```

And to deserialize

```
  List<Contact> test;

  XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Contact>));
  FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream("c:/addressbook.xml",FileMode.Open);

  test = (List<Contact>)mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
```

I didn't change the variable names to make it as clear as possible. I use this method to serialize and deserialize my settings object.

And your Contact class should look like

```
[Serializable]
public class Contact
{
    public string Name "";
}
```

Comment: Of course he could also create a class AdressBook with a List<Contac>. But you nailed the main point : First learn how to serilze, then you can de-serialize.

Comment: @Youri Leenman - Thank you very much for the detailed yet simple explanation. I can't test it as of right now but will do so when I get back into the office tomorrow morning.

Comment: @TaW - Would the creation of a Contact list be a preferable option?

Comment: @JMC: the real question is: where do the data come from??

Comment: @TaW - The data is coming from the XML file itself in this case but will be implemented and edited in the C# application (Edited the question to state this)

Comment: @TaW This might actually be needed. I will test this and update my answer if my findings are that you are correct. Replying to your first comment

Comment: @YouriLeenman All seems to be working thus far for me at least, just fixing some semantic issues with my original XML file itself (formatting and such), thank you very much!